# Сделать запрос по истечению времени в Python - решение с помощью signals и непонятное поведение

Tags: python

Как то я задавал вопроc: [Как сделать запрос по истечению временного интервала в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425109/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-python) Спасибо всем за ответы! Очень помогли! Но я решил сам поэкспериментировать, и, порывшись в интернете, решил решить эту задачу с помощью signals. Вот пример:

Сначала пишем такую вот функцию короткую функцию - это хэндлер, нужен для signals. Все, что он умеет делать, это выдавать исключение:

```
def _handler(signum, frame):
    raise IOError("Waiting for the response too long!!!")
```

Потом создаем декоратор:

```
def repeat_request(func):
"""
The decorator for functions and methods that unavailable to reach response for the first attempt
"""
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            try:
                signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handler)
                signal.alarm(5)
                response = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except IOError:
                continue
            else:
               break
        return response
    return wrapper
```

Метод `get_image_url(self)` находится в классе. Его мы и декорируем с попощью созданого нами декоратора:

```
@repeat_request
get_image_url(self)
```

Хотелось бы закричать "Ура!", так как вроде бы все работает, как и ожидалось: Исполняется запрос с помощью `get_image_url`, и, если нету ответа в течении 5 секунд, он делается вновь. Так может быть до бесконечности, пока ми не получим значение от `get_image_url`

Но вот незадача... После вызова get_image_url я запускаю другую функцию (назовем ее `foo()`), которая работает очень долго (но так и должно быть). Почему-то этот декоратор измеряет время и для нее и выбрысывается исключение "Waiting for the response too long!!!"

Это мое первое использование signals. Поэтому я четко не понимаю механизмы, как это работает. Функцию `foo()` я в декоратор не оборачивал, естественно. Но время замеряется для нее тоже, что выглядит довольно странно...  Пытался больше сам разобраться с signals, но документация скудна и непонятна. Если кто разбирается - просьба помочь

Comment: не по теме: сигналы в Питоне могут быть задержаны на неопределённый срок, если `get_image_url()` вызывает не кооперирующее C расширение. [Ответ с `multiprocessing.Process` продолжает работать и в этом случае](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425114/23044).

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли отменить сигнал, вот и все. Для этого надо выключить alarm - и вернуть на место старый обработчик.

Comment: Да, установил `signal.alarm(0)` и все вылечилось. Как я сразу не заметил, что забыл сбросить таймер...

**и вернуть на место старый обработчик.**
Что конкретнее имеется ввиду и как это сделать?

Comment: `old_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handler)` ... `signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, old_handler)`